# How to change google recaptcha width box using css?

Tags: html, css, recaptcha

How to change google recaptcha width box using css ?

I tried to change google recaptcha width box, but not work , how can i do ?

```
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RVrPVx
```

.

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<div id="recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lc7JBAUAAAAANrF3CJaIjt7T9IEFSmd85Qpc4gj"></div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use **transform** properties here .
You can also check the example [here](https://geekgoddess.com/how-to-resize-the-google-nocaptcha-recaptcha/)

```
.g-recaptcha {
  transform: scale(2);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```css
.g-recaptcha {
  transform: scale(2);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<div id="recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lc7JBAUAAAAANrF3CJaIjt7T9IEFSmd85Qpc4gj"></div>
```

Codepen example [here](http://codepen.io/sahildhir_1/pen/gWPpQB).